# User retention with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to compute user retention with MongoDB, the record in MongoDB is like this:

```
{
    "event" : "$signup",
    "properties" : {
        "country" : "GB",
        "device" : "iPad",
        "ref" : "Facebook",
        "token" : "baddf3b44149c8f836f28d3750d4d6cf",
        "time" : ISODate("2013-03-26T21:16:52Z"),
        "distinct_id" : 8
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("51784bc5c83494cb98000001")
}
```

My idea is :

Step 1, get users signed up some day like 2013-04-01

Step 2, group the result in login time and count

But in practice, I am stuck in the step 1 by this:

```
db.rawData.aggregate(
    {$match: 
        {event: "$signup",
        "$properties.time": {"$gte": new Date(2013, 4, 15), "$lte": new Date(2013, 4, 20)}
        }
    },
    {$group:
        {
            _id:"$properties.distinct_id"
        }
    }
);
```

I can get result without condition for time, but with time condition ,I got nothing.

And I have no idea about the step 2. I'll appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is because you use `"$properties.time"` inside $match, but your field is called `properties`, not `$properties`. I would try with `"properties.time"` there.

Comment: The dollar sign has special meaning for a lot of things in mongodb.  I'd avoid it in your own data where possible.  It's likely to trip you up or at least continue to confuse you.  That is, rename `$signup` to just `signup`.

Comment: "$properties.time": {"$gte": new Date(2013, 4, 15), "$lte": new Date(2013, 4, 20)}. "$properties.time" should be "properties.time" and date format should be Date("4 1 2013").